# Tool for to view route values in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

There are a tool for to check the route values defined in `Global.asax` when I access a page ?

I searched in microsoft website for tool but no success.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ASP.NET MVC Routing Debugger: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx